# How i can fix it Could not find `bin\flutter_application_1.dart` in package `flutter_application_1`

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to Flutter development. I installed Flutter using the video tutorial. I created a Flutter project in VS Code. In the VS Code console I can call `flutter doctor` but when calling `dart run,` I get this error:

```
Could not find `bin\flutter_application_1.dart` in package `flutter_application_1`
```

I also have all the environment variables that are needed set. How can I fix it?

[image]

I tried reinstalling Flutter SDK, rechecked the paths to the packages and created a new project in the hope that it will help me.

Comment: Do you have a main.dart file in your project? What are the contents of your lib folder of your project?

Comment: I have a main.dart file. Everything in it is by default. I can send it if needed.

Comment: lib contains only main.dart

Comment: Then why is the message talking about flutter_application_1.dart? Does this file exist?

Comment: I cant find this file. Should I create this file myself?

Comment: If this file doesn't exist, there is no reason for you to create it. You need to understand what is referencing this file.

Comment: Im find the problem. Thank you

Comment: worth to post an answer to this so other people who may encounter the same problem, will find a solution.